# Modify catalina.policy

Tags: java, eclipse, security, tomcat

Does anyone know how to  modify catalina.policy to eliminate this AccessControlException:

Feb 25, 2016 2:31:14 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener install

```
**SEVERE: TomEE Listener can't start OpenEJB**
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (**"java.util.PropertyPermission" "tomee.skip-tomcat-log" "read"**)
    at
```

java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1294)
at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:717)
at java.lang.Boolean.getBoolean(Boolean.java:254)
**at org.apache.tomee.TomEELogConfigurer.configureLogs(TomEELogConfigurer.java:30)**
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener.install(ServerListener.java:170)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener.lifecycleEvent(ServerListener.java:55)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)

All I did was click on Enable Security in Eclipse and then restarted the server. Tomcat doesn't even have to load a web app to error out.
Tomcat is launched from within Eclipse with the option:
**-Dwtp.configured.security=true**

**For the record:**
Server: Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.62 (1.7.2)
Eclipse: Eclipse Java EE IDE Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
Java: jdk 1.8.0_73

[image: Enable Security checkbox checked in Eclipse on Server Overview page]

Driving me crazy...

Comment: Please do not post links as they may get corrupted in the future. Stackoverflow supports adding images ;)

Comment: Apparently I "need at least 10 reputation points to post an image." Hard to achieve in the first post, and a question at that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I think, there are two ways which I have discovered as a possible solution, only the first tried:

1. especially for development purposes is useful to enable everything in catalina.policy, so put following code to the end of the file, then the error disappeared to me:

`grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};`

2. I looked into the source code where can be found the given permission and found there is following checking of the given property:

`if (!Boolean.getBoolean("tomee.skip-tomcat-log")) {
            // do some log initialisation ...
}`

so, if you set the environment property "tomee.skip-tomcat-log" to "true" for the Tomcat, the property could be read and initialisation should not happen so the exception possibly could not be thrown...

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in TomEE catalina.policy regarding tomcat-juli.
Currently TomEE 8.0.9 and TomEE 9.0.0-M7 are affected.

Add the following two lines to your catalina.policy:

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/bin/tomcat-juli.jar" {
    ...
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "tomee.skip-tomcat-log", "read";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessDeclaredMembers";
   ...
};
```

See:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-3840
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-3843

Feel free to create a bug ticket at TomEE project.